How do I get logs from Sonos apps/devices?
I'm developing a content service, and when I test the service with the Sonos app or the Web app I sometimes get an error message:

Something went wrong

Normally I check my content service's logs at that point, but often see nothing obvious. It maybe that I've returned some invalid data, but from the service's point of view the HTTP request/response was completed with a HTTP 200.
How do I get a detailed description of what the app thought was a problem?

PC app does put some logs in C:\programdata\SonosV2,_Inc\runtime but that's about it.
